# IN clause with Spring Data and Cassandra @Query

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I'm trying to query a Cassandra table using the IN clause and the @Query annotation from Spring Data.  I have a table with a partition key of last_name and a clustering key of first_name.

I have this query working

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE last_name=?0")
public List<People> findByLastName(String lastName);
```

and I would like to do something like

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE last_name=?0 AND first_name IN ?1")
public List<People> findByLastName(String lastName, String[] firstName);
```

I have it working using

```
CassandraOperations.select("SELECT * FROM people WHERE last_name=" + lastName + 
" AND first_name IN (" + concatinatedNameList + ")", People.class);
```

But for a number of reasons (code style, testing, I swear there are more) I would prefer to use @Query.  Any ideas?

**EDIT FOR MORE INFO!**

Passing in an array, set, or list returns `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: encountered unsupported query parameter type [class [Ljava.lang.String;] in method public abstract`

Also tried:

```
String firstName = "Joe,Jim";
@Query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE last_name=?0 AND first_name IN (?1)")
public List<People> findByLastName(String lastName, String firstName);
```

Nothing found, library searches for a single person with a concatinated name `('Joe,Jim')`

```
String firstName = "'Joe','Jim'";
@Query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE last_name=?0 AND first_name IN (?1)")
public List<People> findByLastName(String lastName, String firstName);
```

Nothing found, the request is escaped and ends up `('''Joe'',''Jim''')`

```
String firstName = "Joe','Jim"; // Hoping the library would just add the outer quotes, getting desperate
@Query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE last_name=?0 AND first_name IN (?1)")
public List<People> findByLastName(String lastName, String firstName);
```

Nothing found, the request is escaped and ends up `('Joe'',''Jim')`

Comment: did you try any Collection type? Set or List of strings instead of String array ?

Comment: Both Lists and Sets return an error similar to this on startup

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: encountered unsupported query parameter type [interface java.util.Set]`

Answer (score 11):

**Update**

With current spring, it seems to be working without braces.

---

**Old answer**

You have to use bracers when you are using `IN`.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE last_name=?0 AND first_name IN (?1)")
public List<People> findByLastName(String lastName, String[] firstName);
```

But there are some other issues in your code. I changed them all to a good coding standards as below. Including my personal favorite of using named parameters.

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM People p WHERE p.lastName = :lastName AND p.firstName IN (:firstNames)")
public List<People> findByName(@Param("lastName") String lastName, @Param("firstNames") String[] firstNames);
```

Comment: I wish I could use named parameters, but since I'm actually passing in 7, I end up with `Invalid amount of bind variable` exception.

I am able to get it working when passing in a single string to constrain on, but when passing in an array I see this on startup
    `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: encountered unsupported query parameter type [class [Ljava.lang.String;]`

Comment: Then can you try the first one. your same query with bracets. Like `IN (?1)`

Comment: If I pass in a single name, it does work.  If I pass multiple, it gets wrapped in quotes so the query ends up `IN ('Joe,Jim')`.  Obviously, no one is named 'Joe,Jim'.  I also tried building a request string, `'Joe','Jim'` but when it gets passed in the library escapes all the quotes and I end up with `'''Joe'',''Jim'''`

Comment: I suppose these queries are in interfaces so you don't need public modifier

Comment: With current spring Cassandra it works if you don't  have braces.```@Query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE last_name=?0 AND first_name IN ?1")
public List<People> findByLastName(String lastName, List<String> firstName); ```

Comment: without brakets and using List collection it works for me

Comment: @NitishBhagat - Bulls eye! Thanks. This should also be one of the valid Answers.This solved my issue in `2.0.13.Release` . I was doing IN on List of UUIDs. Now changed it like this -  `@Query("SELECT * FROM users where id in ?0")`

Answer (score 3):

Nitish Bhagat is right, with the current version spring-data-cassandra:2.0.6.RELEASE it does **NOT** work with the braces.

For me, it works ONLY **without** the braces like:

`@Query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE first_name IN ?0")
public List<People> findByFirstName(List<String> firstName);`

Comment: So, you took a comment and made it your own answer?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be not possible!

I checked the source code of [spring-data-cassandra-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/springframework/data/spring-data-cassandra/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-data-cassandra-1.3.2.RELEASE-sources.jar).

The allowed data types of parameter in the query method are 
`String.class, CharSequence.class, char.class, Character.class, char[].class, long.class, Long.class, boolean.class, Boolean.class, BigDecimal.class, BigInteger.class, double.class, Double.class, float.class, Float.class, InetAddress.class, Date.class, UUID.class, int.class are Integer.class`.

They can be found in

```
org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.CassandraQueryMethod.ALLOWED_PARAMETER_TYPES = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays
            .asList(new Class<?>[] { String.class, CharSequence.class, char.class, Character.class, char[].class, long.class,
                    Long.class, boolean.class, Boolean.class, BigDecimal.class, BigInteger.class, double.class, Double.class,
                    float.class, Float.class, InetAddress.class, Date.class, UUID.class, int.class, Integer.class }));
```

If we pass data types other than these, then `org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.CassandraQueryMethod.verify(Method method, RepositoryMetadata metadata)` will throw `IllegalArgumentException`.