# How to impelement the update @Query with IN operator while using spring data cassandra?

Tags: spring-data-cassandra, in-operator

Could anyone help please.

I need to know How to impelement the update @Query with IN operator while using spring data cassandra?

Because I want to use something like this:
@Query("UPDATE objects SET children = ?0 WHERE id IN (?...)")

Ofc if it's possible. Might be I should use native data stax template for this kind of query.

Thx in advance

Comment: Actually it seems that a more accurate answer to your question was posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29418075/in-clause-with-spring-data-and-cassandra-query (although it's probably good to keep in mind what @jny wrote).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to implement it, but it is not recommended to use IN in queries with Cassandra ( see [this blog](http://christopher-batey.blogspot.com/2015/02/cassandra-anti-pattern-distributed.html) for example). It will actually be slower than iterating through the ids and and calling update separately for every id using the standard query, e.g.

```
@Query("UPDATE objects SET children = ?0 WHERE id = ?1")
```