# Using Range to query from Cassandra database in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data

I have a spring-boot application with spring-data-cassandra, I created a repository by extending CassandraRepository, in which one of my query i am trying to use Range(org.springframework.data.domain).

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM atable")
ResultSet findResult(Range myRange);
```

and while executing this query i am passing `new Range(20,40)`, this Range is available in Cassandra database, but while executing this query I am getting IllegalArgumentException.PFB: Exception

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: encountered unsupported query parameter type [class org.springframework.data.domain.Range]`

In this *question*([IN clause with Spring Data and Cassandra @Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29418075/in-clause-with-spring-data-and-cassandra-query)) in allowed Data types Range class is not specified, so, is it possible to query Cassandra in Spring boot app with Range.

Comment: What is your table schema ?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the question you've addressed here,

> question(IN clause with Spring Data and Cassandra @Query)

you need to use filtering in your sql where condition, like here:

```
...  first_name IN (?1)
```